# If $a$ is a root then so is $2-a^2$

Tags: polynomials

Consider the polynomial $P(X)=X^3-X^2-2X+1$

How to prove that if $a$ is a root of $P$ then so is $2-a^2$ ?

Let $a$ be such a root. Then $P(2-a^2)=-a^6+5a^4-6a^2+1$.

Why should $-a^6+5a^4-6a^2+1$ be zero ?

Even if I combine it linearly with $a^3-a^2-2a+1=0$ , I can't manage to prove it.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619512/on-the-roots-of-a-polynomial

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

$$a^6-5a^4+6a^2-1=(a^3-a^2-2a+1)(a^3+a^2-2a-1)$$

Answer (score 3):

Divide the polynomial $-x^6 + 5 x^4-6 x^2 + 1$ by your original polynomial. You will see that the remainder is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

You can factor $P(2-a^2)$:
\begin{align}
P(2-a^2)&=-a^6+5a^4-6a^2+1\\&=(a^3-a^2-2a+1)(-a^2-a^2+2a+1)\\&=P(a)(-a^2-a^2+2a+1)=0
\end{align}
so $2-a^2$ is a root for any root $a$.

Answer (score 0):

I got it somehow:

Let $A=-a^6+5a^4-6a^2+1$

Let $B=a^3-a^2-2a+1=0$

$A+Ba^3=-a^5+3a^4+a^3-6a^2+1=A$

Hence $A+Ba^2=-a^5+3a^4+a^3-6a^2+1+Ba^2=2a^4-a^3-5a^2+1=A$

Hence $A-Ba=2a^4-a^3-5a^2+1-Ba=a^3-a^2-2a+1=B=A=0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Since $\ p(a)=0\Rightarrow q(a) := p(2-a^2)=0\,$ we suspect that $\,p(a)\,$ divides $\,q(a).\,$  Then also $\,p(-a)\,$ divides $\,q(-a) = q(a),\,$ so $\,q(a)=p(a)p(-a).\,$ This suggests seeking a differences of squares factorization. Indeed

$$\begin{eqnarray} p(2\!-\!a^2)\ &=&\qquad  (2\!-\!a^2)^3-\,(2\!-\!a^2)^2-2\,(2\!-\!a^2)+1\\
&=&\: -a^2(2\!-\!a^2)^2 +\,(2\!-\!a^2)^2-2\,(2\!-\!a^2)+1\\
&=&\ -(2a-a^3)^2\! + (2\!-\!a^2\, -\, 1)^2\\
&=&\ -(2a-a^3)^2\! + (1-a^2)^2 \quad \text{a difference of squares}\\
&=&\  \ \:(-2a+a^3\ \  +\ \  1-a^2)\\
&& \,*\, \ \  (2a-a^3\ \ \,+\ \  1-a^2)\\
&=&\ \ \ p(a)\,p(-a)
\end{eqnarray}$$